# JSF как загрузить файл с сервера без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: jsf

Здравствуйте, мне нужно загрузить файл с сервера. И при некоторых условия вместо загрузки вывести сообщение, что загружать нечего.

Вот моя страничка index.xhtml :

```
<h:form >

<p:commandButton id="export_xls" value="export" ajax="false"
                                 action="#{excelManager.export}" />

</h:form>
```

сам бин:

```
 @PresentationModel
        class  ExcelManager{

           void export() {

                if(notOk){
                   Notification.error( "error", "details");
                   return;
                } 

                    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("PF('expDialog').hide()")  
                    // собираем файл и отсылаем его
                    Faces.sendFile(output.toByteArray(), fileName, true);                  
           }
        }
```

Но проблема в том, что после клика по кнопке, страница перезагружается, и сообщение о том, что "*не получилось загрузить*" пропадает.
Пробовал ставить

```
ajax="true"
```

Тогда страница не перезагружается, все сообщения приходят нормально, но нельзя загрузить файл :)

Помогите, подскажите решение, можно ли сделать так, чтобы для загрузки файла не требовалась перезагрузка странцы?

Comment: Вряд ли jsf поможет в этом деле. Ведь так устроен html и jsf его не переделает. Просто разметите на странице ссылку для загрузки с помощью например <h:outputLink>

Comment: Да, но у меня нет ссылки на файл. Файл создается после клика на кнопку "export".

Comment: Всё тривиально. Пользователь щёлкает по ссылке, сервер получает запрос и на лету создаёт файл и выдаёт его в качестве ответа. Можете стилизовать ссылку под кнопку, чтобы была ... кнопка

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по всему, в проекте используется Primefaces. Этот фреймворк позволяет решить Вашу задачу достаточно просто, но с некоторыми хитростями. Код страницы следующий:

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton action="#{downloadController.checkValidation}"
                     update="msgs"
                     value="Скачать"
                     oncomplete="if(args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('downloadHidden').jq.click();"/>

    <p:commandButton ajax="false" style="visibility: hidden" widgetVar="downloadHidden">
                <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadController.createFile()}" contentDisposition="attachment"/>
    </p:commandButton>

    <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="false"/>
</h:form>
```

Серверный контроллер:

```
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

@Named
@RequestScoped
public class DownloadController {

private static int counter;//счётчик для тестирования

public void checkValidation() {
    if (counter++ % 2 == 0) {//для тестирования - возвращаем ошибку через раз (только при чётных значениях счётчика)
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Validation failed!");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();//проверяется в commandButton.oncomplete
    }
}

    public DefaultStreamedContent createFile() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream("Some generated content".getBytes()),
            "text/plain", URLEncoder.encode("newfile.txt", "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Процесс следующий:

- При нажатии кнопки "Скачать" осуществляется вызов метода `downloadController.checkValidation`, который осуществляет проверку ваших условий
- По завершению вызова метода `downloadController.checkValidation` уже на клиенте (в браузере) вызывается обработчик события `oncomplete`
- В `oncomplete` проверяется, были ли ошибки валидации. Если ошибок не было, то осуществляется программное нажатие скрытой кнопки `downloadHidden` (с помощью JavaScript). Кнопка запускает непосредственно процесс скачивания.
- Если валидаця не пройдена, то в `oncomplete` не делается ничего. При этом, в кнопке "Скачать" указано, что следует обновить элемент вывода сообщений об ошибках `p:growl` (`update="msgs"`). В результате - файл не скачивается, а пользователю выводится сообщение об ошибке.

*PS Контроллер в моём примере имеет аннотации согласно спецификации Java EE. Похоже на то, что у Вас в проекте используется какой-то другой серверный контейнер, поэтому Вам, скорее всего, следует заменить аннотации класса `DownloadController`.*

Comment: спасибо, ваше решение помогло.

Comment: а зачем нужно  "args &amp;&amp;" в этой строчке if(args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) PF('downloadHidden').jq.click();" ?

Comment: `&amp;&amp;` следует читать как `&&`, т.е. как булевый оператор `AND` в `JavaScript`. `HTML` и `XHTML` - это расширения стандарта `XML`, в котором символ _амперсанда_ `&` является зарезервированным, его нельзя вставлять в "чистом" виде. Вместо этого его следует экранировать (_escape_). `XML-парсер` при разборе страницы принимает `&amp;` и преобразует в `&`